# arch linux laptop not recognizing partitions or filesystems on internal windows SDA drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, arch-linux, fdisk

I bought a laptop with windows 11 and installed arch linux on it. The laptop has 3 internal 500GB SSDs. Two of them are in a RAID configuration to make a single 1TB partition which Windows came installed on. I installed Arch on the empty third SSD.

UEFI settings/BIOS recognizes all drives and I can easily boot into both Windows and Arch by changing the boot priority from the settings boot menu. Windows also recognizes the linux drive and filesystem.

I'm trying to add Windows to GRUB so I don't have to go into BIOS settings every time I want to switch, but for some reason my linux system isn't recognizing the windows filesystem, and fdisk doesn't even seem to recognize the drive at all.

Running lsblk gives me this:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1     0B  0 disk 
zram0       254:0    0     4G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   511M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 476.4G  0 part /
```

Nvme0n1 is my linux drive and I think sda is the windows drive but it doesn't see the filestructure or size and isn't mountable.

fdisk -l gives this:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: PC SN530 NVMe WDC 512GB                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0E662EC6-E4A2-4F83-9A20-2A762CA47690

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1048575   1046528   511M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/zram0: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Secureboot is off and both windows and arch are installed with modern UEFI, not legacy bios. The fact that I can boot into both systems and Windows has not problem seeing the Linux drive makes me think it must not be a hardware issue like a bad cord or connection or whatever. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Please show `lsblk` and `blkid`. Also, how does it look in Windows?

Comment: You need to add support for Dynamic Disks. Have you done that? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dynamic_disks